# Git - Visual Studio 2013 - Publish to VS Online

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I am currently exploring the built in Git functionality within VS2013.

I have setup a VS online account and have created an empty test project. From within VS, I have created a test app, added it to source control, and made an initial commit (locally). I now want to publish this test app to the empty project within VS online however, I am not having much luck. I have been following the steps listed [here](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/share-your-code-in-git-vs.aspx) but when it gets to step three, I have no option to "Publish to 'project name'". How can I go about adding existing apps to a VS online project? I have viewed several videos on YouTube however they really do not cover this and they are all based on VS 2012. Should I use another app such as TortoiseGit or GitExtensions for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workflow listed on the webpage you linked to should work (I just verified on my own machine). Are you sure that when you created the team project you selected Git as your source control rather than TFVC? That would cause the behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the response and sorry for the delay. I just created a new project in VS online and made sure to select Git as opposed to TFVC. I made an initial commit. Upon making the initial commit, I was provided the option of syncing. Using the sync link that was provided, I was able to accomplish what I was after. I guess if you follow these steps everything works?